# Spring cloud stream 3.0 application failed to start with multiple beans

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream

I'm new to spring cloud stream. I'm using rabbitMQ binder.
The issue is when I start the application with single bean in the main class, Then it's successfully starting. But if I register more than 1 bean in the main class then the application is failed to start with the below log.

```
2020-09-18 12:41:45.698  INFO 27416 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.integration.IntegrationAutoConfiguration$IntegrationJmxConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.integration.IntegrationAutoConfiguration$IntegrationJmxConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-09-18 12:41:45.706  INFO 27416 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jmx.JmxAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jmx.JmxAutoConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-09-18 12:41:45.712  INFO 27416 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'mbeanServer' of type [com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-09-18 12:41:45.730  INFO 27416 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'integrationChannelResolver' of type [org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-09-18 12:41:45.732  INFO 27416 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'integrationDisposableAutoCreatedBeans' of type [org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.Disposables] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-09-18 12:41:46.371  INFO 27416 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
2020-09-18 12:41:46.384  INFO 27416 --- [           main] o.s.c.f.c.c.SimpleFunctionRegistry       : Looking up function '' with acceptedOutputTypes: []
2020-09-18 12:41:46.627  INFO 27416 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Registering MessageChannel errorChannel
2020-09-18 12:41:46.722  INFO 27416 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Registering MessageChannel nullChannel
2020-09-18 12:41:46.756  INFO 27416 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Registering MessageHandler errorLogger
2020-09-18 12:41:46.791  INFO 27416 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
2020-09-18 12:41:46.791  INFO 27416 --- [           main] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : Channel 'application.errorChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2020-09-18 12:41:46.791  INFO 27416 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger'
2020-09-18 12:41:46.804  INFO 27416 --- [           main] com.***.RabbitMQTest             : Started RabbitMQTest in 2.441 seconds (JVM running for 4.047)
2020-09-18 12:41:46.814  INFO 27416 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Removing {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
2020-09-18 12:41:46.815  INFO 27416 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : Channel 'application.errorChannel' has 0 subscriber(s).
2020-09-18 12:41:46.815  INFO 27416 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : stopped bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger'
2020-09-18 12:41:46.817  INFO 27416 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
2020-09-18 12:41:46.822  INFO 27416 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Summary on shutdown: bean 'errorChannel'
2020-09-18 12:41:46.823  INFO 27416 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Summary on shutdown: nullChannel
2020-09-18 12:41:46.823  INFO 27416 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Summary on shutdown: bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger.handler' for component '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger'
`
```

```
 @SpringBootApplication
 public class RabbitMQTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RabbitMQTest.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Function<String, String> toUpperCase() {
        return value -> {
            return value.toUpperCase();
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public Consumer<String> reverse() {
       return value -> new StringBuilder(value).reverse().toString();
    }

 }
```

application.yml file

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        toUpperCase:
          binder: rabbitTest
          destination: toUpperCase-out-0
        reverse:
            binder: rabbitTest
      binders:
        rabbitTest:
          type: rabbit
          environment:
            spring:
              rabbitmq:
                host: localhost
                port: 5672
                virtual-host: /
                username: ***
                password: ***
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to define definition property when we have more than one bean. from doc

*We are using --spring.cloud.function.definition property to explicitly declare which function bean we want to be bound to binding destinations. For cases when you only have single such bean it is not required but for all other cases it is*

.